# Find first point with regex

Tags: regex

I want a regex which return me only characters before first point.

Ex :

T420_02.DOMAIN.LOCAL

I want only T420_02

Please help me.

Comment: What language? Which regex flavor? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What problems do you have with the expression you are currently using? Please post it, otherwise we cannot help you. In case you didn't know: This is not McRegex where you can drive by and order an expression. Have a look at the tutorial at http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html and try something. In fact, depending on the language you are using, you might not even need regex at all.

Comment: You're looking for `indexOf()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex: `^(.*?)(?=\.)`
The [*captured group*](http://rubular.com/r/yhtb5bbfNp) contains what you need (T420_02 in your example).

Answer (score 1):

This simple expression should do what you need, assuming you want to match it at the beginning of the string:

```
^(.+?)\.
```

The capture group contains the string before (but not including) the `.`.

Here's a fiddle: http://www.rexfiddle.net/s8l0bn3

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern `^[^.]+(?=[.])`